# How do I solve repeated code caused by dialogue boxes on my switch case method?

Tags: java, android

```
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            double p,d;
            try {
                switch (view.getId()) {
                    case R.id.button:
                        p = Float.parseFloat(e.getText().toString());
                        d = p * 1.41;
                        e.setText("£" + p + " = " + "$" + d);
                        adb.setTitle("£ to $");
                        adb.setMessage("£" + p + " = " + "$" + d);
                        adb.show();
                        break;
                    case R.id.button2:
                        p = Float.parseFloat(e.getText().toString());
                        d = p * 1.14;
                        e.setText("£" + p + " = " + "€" + d);
                        adb.setTitle("£ to €");
                        adb.setMessage("£" + p + " = " + "€" + d);
                        adb.show();
                        break;
                }
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException e)
            {
                d = 0.0;
            }
        }
    };
```

On my code i have `adb.setMessage` which repeats what `e.setText("£" + p + " = " + "$" + d);` has in brackets. Is there any way to solve this issue?

I also have a problem where `adb.show();` is repeated and would love to know how I can solve this. Thanks!

Comment: I suggest you use the Android Studio debugger to step through your code to see what it is doing. Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems for tips.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Maybe my question wasnt clear sorry, I just wanted to know if there is a more efficient way of implementing dialogue boxes in my switch case as there is repeated code

Comment: okay, I was confused if you were asking about repetition in your output vs repetition in the actual code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are only 2 differences, so assign those to variables, and share the rest:

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    String currency;
    double rate;
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.button:
            currency = "$";
            rate = 1.41;
            break;
        case R.id.button2:
            currency = "€";
            rate = 1.14;
            break;
        default:
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Unknown button");
    }
    try {
        double p = Double.parseDouble(e.getText().toString());
        double d = p * rate;
        e.setText("£" + p + " = " + currency + d);
        adb.setTitle("£ to " + currency);
        adb.setMessage("£" + p + " = " + currency + d);
        adb.show();
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        e.setText("Not a valid number: " + e.getText());
    }
}
```

I fixed the copy/paste error in `adb.setMessage` where it said `$` for `button2`.

I also fixed the number parsing to use `Double`.

Comment: I didn't think to do it this way, its easier to read too. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Here the differences between the two cases is only in values used. And those values are hardcoded literals. Both of these clues suggest that you can refactor the common code into a method:

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.button:
            showCurrency("$", 1.41);
            break;
        case R.id.button2:
            showCurrency("€", 1.14);
            break;
        default:
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Unknown button");
    }
}

private void showCurrency(currency, rate) {
    try {
        double p = Double.parseDouble(e.getText().toString());
        double d = p * rate;
        e.setText("£" + p + " = " + currency + d);
        adb.setTitle("£ to " + currency);
        adb.setMessage("£" + p + " = " + currency + d);
        adb.show();
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        e.setText("Not a valid number: " + e.getText());
    }
}
```

**Additional suggestions**

Personally, I prefer giving each button its own handler, rather than using a switch statement in a single handler:

```
public void onClick1(View view) {
    showCurrency("$", 1.41);
}

public void onClick2(View view) {
    showCurrency("€", 1.14);
}
```

This only works if you set the `onClick` handler in XML and these methods are in an activity. If you are calling `setOnClickListener()` in `onCreate()`, then you will need to create two anonymous inner classes instead of implementing the `OnClickListener` interface in your Activity class.